# jQuery - How to start function on <a> before switch to herf

Tags: jquery

I want to create a website with smooth trasmition. I did this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    $("html").hide();
    $("html").fadeIn("slow");
...
```

for fadeIn, but now I want to set somehow this:

```
...
$("a").click(function(){
        $("html").fadeOut("slow");
    });
...
```

But I want `html` to fadeOut before it's switch to next site.

I know I can do it like I'll change all `<a>` to just `id`s and create link by jQuery, but I want to ask for easier way.

Comment: Maybe you can use `onbeforeunload`, but in general I think this is a bad idea. You are basically slowing down the process, delaying the new page to load, so this will negatively affect user experience. They may 'awe' once or twice and after that, it will annoy them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USe this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    $("html").hide();
 setTimeout(function(){
         $("html").fadeIn("slow");
    }, 1000);
...
```

and

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var MainHref = $(this).attr('href');
    $("html").fadeOut("slow");
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location = MainHref ;
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution works fine, I just change fadeOut speed to fast and setTimeout to 200 and it's work perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

prevent `<a>` default action and create a timeout then redirect to `href` try this one:

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $("html").fadeOut("slow");
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location= href;
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<a href='//link here' onclick='myFunction(event)'>

function myFunction(e)
{
var that = this;

// prevent fade from firing on mid-click
    e.preventDefault();

    $('html').fadeOut(2000, function(){
        window.location.href = that.href;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tray this if you don't want load the new html with ajax

```
$('a').click(function() {   
    event.preventDefault();    

    newLocation = this.href;

    $('body').fadeOut(1000, newpage);

    });

    function newpage() {    
        window.location = newLocation;    
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must disable link switch by returning false in your click callback and after you're finished your transition , you should go to redirect in your new location like this:

$(document).ready(function () {

```
$("a").click(function(){
    var href = this.href;
    $("html").fadeOut("slow", function() { window.location.href = href; } );
    return false;
});
```

});